# "Bear something in mind" or "Bear in mind something"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I've been seeing both of these constructions all around, and I'd like to know if there is any rule that controls the usage of this expression.

For what I've read, it seems to me that "**Bear something in mind**" is used when that something is short, or a single word, like "Bearing this in mind we have that..."

On the other hand, "**Bear in mind something**" seems to be used when that something in longer, or even just longer than a single word, like "Bearing in mind both of those previous things...".

Any confirmation on this? What would you use if you are referring to an annotation? (e.g. "Bearing [1] in mind..." or "Bearing in mind theorems [1] and [2]...").

Comment: As you are already aware of.. both construction my be used, chose the one you forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural phrase is "Bear X in mind", the other construction always a second choice.

The X is a direct object, and English prefers to put direct and indirect objects without prepositions before prepositional phrases:  "Give John the book", but "Give the book to John".

On the other hand, we also do not like to put the parts of uncommon idioms too far apart.

This particular idiom tends to take phrases in 'that' or 'whether', which are hard to get out of cleanly.  So we push those to the end, after the prepositional phrase that closes idioms of this form, to avoid confusion.

I would go with "Bear theorems [1] and [2] in mind" because it does not have this closing-a-phrase problem.  But "Bear in mind that blah, blah blah."

Comment: Note that the last examples in the question use the _present participle_, which tends to licence a different word order with idioms like this than finite forms. “Bearing this in mind” is still fine, but I would prefer “Bearing in mind theorems [1] and [2]” to “Bearing theorems [1] and [2] in mind”—especially if the thing thus in mind borne is definite: “Bearing in mind the results from [1] and [2] …”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Heh, you used *licence* as a verb!

Comment: @tchrist, I always do (variant BrE spelling). ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The noun is *licence* and the verb is *license* **in British spelling**.  Honest.  It’s like *advice*, *device*, *practice*, *prophecy* for the noun and *advise*, *devise*, *practise*, and *prophesy* for the verb. [See here](http://books.google.com/books?id=fNfebt79zdwC&pg=PT120&lpg=PT120&dq=advise+advise+license+licence+devise+devise+prophesy+prophecy&source=bl&ots=aMABsHax-B&sig=Wg-6fxhsAq6FMHlRlej18Qt9Drc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZoNyU83YJtipyATSzYDYAg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=advise%20advise%20license%20licence%20devise%20devise%20prophesy%20prophecy&f=false).

Comment: @tchrist, [ahem](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107946). The OED has both spellings for the verb (and for the noun, though only in the etymological comment). It’s older and less common, but both the OED and ODO mention it as a valid variant spelling in BrE.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I know, but why would you want to go and bust up a perfectly logical system and replace it with random and unpredictable changes? Using *-ce* for nouns and *-se* for verbs makes sence.  Now you have to unlearn that neat system for something you’ll find it harder to defense. :)

Comment: Yeah, but that it is a participle does not matter.  It is still 'Giving my aunt and her sister the book was a good idea'.  So your preference is baseless.  Objects without prepositions fall right after the verb or even the participle -- 'Carrying the packages on my back, I rounded the corner', not 'Carrying on my back the packages...', unless you have a good reason (like you are also carrying something in your arms... and the phrase gets long).  You can't get more parallel than 'bear' vs 'carry'.